# Accessing GWT reflected classes cache in LibGDX application

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, reflection, libgdx

Is there a way to access the whole cache of GWT-reflected classes? I have checked `ReflectionCache` and `IReflectionCache` in GWT LibGDX back-end classes, but they do not seem to have direct access to the classes' collection. Basically, I want to do something similar to a component scan (finding all classes with specific annotations, without actually registering them anyway before) and I'm having trouble accessing all (reflected) classes used by the application.

Comment: I don't believe there is such a list in the ReflectionCache implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes are stored in *static* fields (c0, c1, ..., cN) in the generated class and there are no direct getter methods, so accessing them (even with JSNI) is rather problematic. I think that writing a custom class generator that scans types similarly to LibGDX scanner and contains an array of all reflected classes is the simplest way to go.

Comment: Custom class pool generator example, based on the actual reflection pool generator used by LibGDX: https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-autumn-gwt/blob/master/src/com/github/czyzby/autumn/gwt/reflection/generator/ReflectionPoolGenerator.java